# Content.IE5 Access is denied when executing tensorboard on windows 10

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10, tensorboard

I'm getting Access is denied error when executing `tensorboard --logdir .` on Windows 10 `cmd` . `cmd` executed as `Administrator`

```
Exception in thread Reloader:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python36-64\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "c:\python36-64\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "c:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 361, in _reload_forever
reload_multiplexer(multiplexer, path_to_run)
 File "c:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 333, in reload_multiplexer
multiplexer.AddRunsFromDirectory(path, name)
File "c:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\plugin_event_multiplexer.py", line 175, in AddRunsFromDirectory
for subdir in GetLogdirSubdirectories(path):
File "c:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\plugin_event_multiplexer.py", line 445, in <genexpr>
subdir
File "c:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\io_wrapper.py", line 50, in ListRecursively
for dir_path, _, filenames in tf.gfile.Walk(top):
File "c:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 518, in walk
for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
File "c:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 518, in walk
for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
 File "c:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 518, in walk
for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
[Previous line repeated 5 more times]
File "c:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 499, in walk
listing = list_directory(top)
File "c:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 478, in list_directory
compat.as_bytes(dirname), status)
File "c:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: FindFirstFile failed for: C:\WINDOWS\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.IE5 : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
```

I tried following `icacls Content.IE5 /remove:d Everyone /T`

and that `icacls Content.IE5 /deny *S-1-1-0:(OI)(CI)(DE,DC)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution?